# How to use timer and input random numbers in java?

Tags: java, random, timer

can anyone teach me how to use a timer in java,

for example: i want my oval to appear after 5 seconds. and how to put random coordinates/width/height, for example:

`g.drawOval()`<-- numbers inside should be `random`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a timer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create variables containing double values generated with a randomizer.

```
double coordx=Math.random(); //this creates a random double value between 0 and 0.9999
double coordy=Math.random()*5;//between 0 and 4.9999
double width=(Math.random()+1)*5;//between 1 and 5.999
```

then you write a method like

```
public void drawIt(double coordx, double coordy, double width){
   Thread.sleep(1000); //time in miliseconds to wait before continuing
   g.drawOval(coordx,coordy,width); //i assume you already have drawOval and g
}
```

hope this helped you.

even easier version:

```
public void drawIt(){
double coordx=Math.random(); //this creates a random double value between 0 and 0.9999
double coordy=Math.random()*5;//between 0 and 4.9999
double width=(Math.random()+1)*5;//between 1 and 5.999
Thread.sleep(1000); //time in miliseconds to wait before continuing
g.drawOval(coordx,coordy,width); //i assume you already have drawOval and g
}
```

Comment: problem, only one shape is appearing, i wanted for the shapes to appear at the same time every 2 seconds. and how can i put the Thread.sleep(1000); here
i was having an error. (cant post my code T_T need to wait for 8hrs)

Comment: public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  Random rand = new Random();
  int x = rand.nextInt(750);
  int y = rand.nextInt(750);
  int w = rand.nextInt(750);
  int h = rand.nextInt(750);
  int w2 = rand.nextInt(50);
  int h2 = rand.nextInt(50);
  int R = (int) (Math.random( )*256);
  int G = (int)(Math.random( )*256);
  int B= (int)(Math.random( )*256);
  Color randomColor = new Color(R, G, B);

  g.setColor(randomColor);
  g.fillOval(x,y,w,h);

  g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);

  g.fillRoundRect(x,y,w,h,w2,h2);
  Thread.sleep(1000);
 }

Comment: glad you found a solution yourself :)