# send value location continues after 10 minute

Tags: android, database, latitude-longitude

i want to send my location into my database..
i have code to get location (longitude and latitude) like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    updateWithNewLocation(null);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 10,
                                           locationListener);

}
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
      updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                Bundle extras){ }
  };
  private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
        //EditText etlat=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lat);
        //EditText etlong=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lng);


        if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            System.out.println(lat);
             double lng = location.getLongitude();
             System.out.println(lng);
             double alt = location.getAltitude();
             System.out.println(alt);
             etlat.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
             etlng.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
             etalt.setText(String.valueOf(alt));
        } 
  }
```

and then i want to save my location continues into database with interval 10 minute..
how can i do this??thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,(10*60*1000),10,
                                           locationListener);
```

You can try this.

Comment: Yes ..replace it with your existing line...
the (10*60*1000) are the millis after every these much millis device will start locating itself..

Comment: it's automatically save value from longitude and latitude into database after 10 minutes??

Comment: if I create code database insertion in updateWithNewLocation method it's can save automatically into database with interval 10 minutes??thank you

Comment: how can make it run in background??so my application close,it's always run?sorry to bother you :)

Comment: no problem...
You 'll have to make a "Service" which keeps running even if you'r activities are closed.

Comment: how can I make this "Service" ??

Answer (score 1):

Write a class that extends Service and add the appropriate tag in your manifest file.

Write the code that you want to execute when service is running like fetching location and saving it in database in onCreate() method.

You can refer to this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Just start the timer with interval of 10 minutes.. and the make requestLocationUpdate();

then u will get set of lat, log values for each GPS fix.. get best value from it by location.getAccuracy().. and write the code for database insertion.

Comment: how can i set timer with interval of 10 minutes?

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java