# In Java, how do I execute code every X seconds?

Tags: java, timer, execute

I'm making a really simple snake game, and I have an object called Apple which I want to move to a random position every X seconds. So my question is, what is the easiest way to execute this code every X seconds?

```
apple.x = rg.nextInt(470);
apple.y = rg.nextInt(470);
```

Thanks.

Edit:

Well do have a timer already  like this:

```
Timer t = new Timer(10,this);
t.start();
```

What it does is draw my graphic elements when the game is started, it runs this code:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        Graphics e = this.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        e.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        ep.drawApple(e);
        se.drawMe(g);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a timer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

Comment: I do have a timer, I edited my question so you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Does your snake game have threading?

Comment: No, I have no idea what threading is, haha. ^_^

Comment: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/

Comment: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8d_Game_Framework.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing is to use `Thread.sleep()`.

```
apple.x = rg.nextInt(470);
apple.y = rg.nextInt(470);
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Run the above code in loop.

This will give you an **approximate** (may not be exact) one second delay.

Answer (score 8):

I would use an executor

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable toRun = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("your code...");
        }
    };
ScheduledFuture<?> handle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(toRun, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a timer:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
int begin = 1000; //timer starts after 1 second.
int timeinterval = 10 * 1000; //timer executes every 10 seconds.
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //This code is executed at every interval defined by timeinterval (eg 10 seconds) 
   //And starts after x milliseconds defined by begin.
  }
},begin, timeinterval);
```

Documentation: [Oracle documentation Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long))

Answer (score 1):

You should have some sort of game loop which is responsible for processing the game. You can trigger code to be executed within this loop every *x* milliseconds like so:

```
while(gameLoopRunning) {
    if((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastExecution) >= 1000) {
        // Code to move apple goes here.

        lastExecution = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

In this example, the condition in the if statement would evaluate to `true` every 1000 milliseconds.