# How to add a number to a table cell after a certain time

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I'm very very new at programming, so please be gentle. I've been working with Dreamweaver for only a few days and I'm having trouble with adding 2 to a number in a cell, when the clock shows `XX:00:00` or `XX:30:00`. In other words, I want the number 2 added to the content of the cell every half hour.

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result of that? What error did you get? What programming language do you use? Please provide more information when asking questions.

Comment: Just so you know java != javascript...;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you would like to add 2 to some value every half hour?
You have tagged your post as both Java and Javascript, those are two different languages, so please correct. Since you have worked in Dreamviewer I assume you are developing web pages and the language you want to use is Javascript.

Setting a timer in Javascript:

```
setInterval(function(){myFunc()},1800000);  //1800000 = 30 minutes in milliseconds
function myFunc()
{
    //Code to update the cell
}
```

If you actually meant Java, the question is answered here: [How to set a timer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java).

Comment: I was referring to javascript, thanks for the reply, I'll try it as soon as I get home.