# Capturing burst pictures via an android app

Tags: android, image

I am developing an app in which I need to click a series of images, say 10 shots in 30 seconds..

So I guess taking burst pictures is an option,but how do I do it?

I want the app to work in such a way that on a single click, ten images must be clicked and must be stored..

Any help - blogs discussing this or the code itself - will be appreciated

Comment: U must b using custom camera app, not the default android app, right?

Comment: If there is way to use the default camera app I don't mind.. I just want continuous shots to be taken without any user interaction in between the shots..

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a custom Android application for example by using a timer that starts on a button click and calls `takePicture` in its `run()` function. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java) stackoverflow question on how to use a timer.