# Show and Hide Bitmap In Surfaceview android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple game where, i want to have 5 bitmaps in surface view and they are shown and hidden randomly .As i have placed all bitmaps, now how to hide and show bitmaps In surface view randomly. 
I do not want to have a layer above those bitmap as my background is moving

Comment: Maybe you could store the positions for each bitmap in a `List` of some kind and then with a `post runnable` youiterate through the list randomly and hide an image at each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate 5 random numbers from 0 - 1

```
int randomOne =  (int) ((Math.random()); //repeat this 4 more times
```

within your canvas, choose to draw or not draw those bitmaps because of the random number selected

```
if (randomOne == 1)
{
     canvas.drawBitmap((Bitmap)bitmapName,x,y,null);
} 
//repeat this 4 more times
```

if you wish to constantly change whether or not these bitmaps are shown, use a [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)