# Call A Method From a different Class JAVA

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have this method called "createAlarms()" which is on initial app setup, sets an alarm for a specific time. On the running of this alarm, it creates a notification which I am creating using a Broadcast Receiver Class.

```
public void createAlarms() {
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, alarmintervalint);
    calintent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    calpendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 12345, calintent, 0);
    am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmintervalint, calpendingintent);
}
```

I want this alarm to repeat every "alarmintervalint" time period. I could do this by using the "am.setRepeating()" function, but my problem is a bit more complicated then that. After sending a certain amount of alarms (such as 50. will be calculated by the program), I want all the values to change, so that the alarmintervalint will change.

```
private void showNotification(Context context) {
    PendingIntent notifpi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, Main.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Hello!")
        .setContentText("Welcome!")
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Open App", notifpi);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(notifpi);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    System.out.println("6");

}
```

For example, right now, an alarm goes off every 2 hours, and I get a notification every 2 hours. After getting 50 notifications, I want to set the Alarm to go off after 3 hours. And again after 50 notifications, make it 4 hours. (This is just an example, it will be a bit more complicated.

How would I do this? Right now what I think is to have some sort of counter in my broadcastreceiver class, and after the counter reaches 50 (in this example's case), it will call upon the createAlarms() class and change the timings and stuff. Would this work?

Comment: You yourself have given the solution to it. Yes setting a counter and at certain interval resetting the alarms will work. You can also have some incremental set in the setAlarm() itself which should increment the interval after 50.

Comment: Yes but how would I call this method since it is in a different class? And is this the most effective way to do this?

Comment: Make the method static and you will be able to call with classname.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to use the `Timer`. Set `TimerTask` in your initial setup method, main method or whatever.

Example :

```
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Schedular extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your implementation.
        System.out.println("Run Me ~");
    }
}

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        TimerTask task = new Schedular();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        //miliseconds
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 60000);
    }
}
```

For Ref : [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what you're using the alarm for, but it looks like you want people to gradually smoke less often.
In that case I'd like to add to the previous answers, that you might want to persist your last used interval in case your app crashes or the phone is rebooted. You can easily archieve that by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).