# Running a counter thread in the background during a game

Tags: java, multithreading

I am wondering the best way to keep a timer going in the background while a game is played.

I am programming a version of the HiLo game (in Java), which gives a user a certain amount of time to determine a number. If a guess is not correct, the game will tell the user whether the name is too high or too low.

I'm keeping track of time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and seeing how much time has elapsed. This seems to work well, and so far I have been checking to see how much time has elapsed each time a new number is entered. For example, currently the app output looks like this:

```
  Welcome to HiLo! 
  You have 10 seconds to guess a number I'm thinking of between 1 and 100.

  > 67 
  Too high.

  > 29
   Too low.

  Half of your time is gone! Only 5 seconds remains!

  > 37
  Too high.

  > 33

  Oops! Time is up - try again.
```

As you can see, currently, it can only check when I enter a new number how much time is passed.

I have tried creating a thread to start with a timer, however, when I start it, it keeps counting until the time is exhausted, without going on to the thread.run(int guess) which will be run when there is a new guess. I want to be able to still make guesses while the counter runs. Here is my attempt at a new implementation for thread.start():

```
public void start(int time_sent) throws InterruptedException {
    time = time_sent; 

    startTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

    while (1==1) {
        long elapsed = ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) - (startTime));
        if (elapsed >= (time)) {
            System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (elapsed >= (time/2) && !halfWarning) {
            System.out.println("Half of your time is gone! Only " + (time/2) + " seconds remains!");
            halfWarning = true;
        }
    }

}
```

How can I continue running this counter in the background?

Comment: A better option would be to use a Timer. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java/4044793#4044793

Comment: Why would you want to write a new thread.start? Can you post more code?

Comment: Apart from using a Timer: Re-implementing `Thread.start()` isn`t proper thread handling. See its JavaDoc: _"Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread."_. So your thread's logic has to be implemented in `run()`. The thread ends when its `run()` method ends. See examples at the beginning of `Thread`'s JavaDoc. Furthermore, `System.exit()` is a brute way to end a program. I'd rather let all associated methods end until `main()` finally ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one more approach:

```
public void game() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int time = 10; // sec

    message("You have " + time + " seconds to guess...");
    new Thread(new Background(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000, time)).start();

    while (true) {
        String s = scanner.next();

        if (s.equals("55")) {
            message("You win");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            message("try again...");
        }
    }

}

private void message(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.print("> "); // monit
}
```

You start 1 thread with behavior implemented in Background class. Next you enter while loop to capture user inputs. The Background thread works in background...

```
private class Background implements Runnable {

    private long startTime;
    private long time;
    private boolean halfWarning;

    private Background(long startTime, long time) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            long elapsed = now - startTime;

            if (elapsed >= (time / 2) && !halfWarning) {
                message("\n Half of your time is gone! Only " + (time / 2) + " seconds remains!");
                halfWarning = true;
            }

            if (elapsed >= time) {
                message("\n Oops! Time is up - try again.");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of good solutions, but this was similar to what I was doing and good to integrate. Thank you for very much for the help!

Comment: How to maintain timer in background thread if its a swing GUI application

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to execute concurrent actions in the future:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
ScheduledFuture<?> half = ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Half of your time is gone!");
    }
}, time / 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ScheduledFuture<?> full = ses.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Oops! Time is up - try again.");
        // System.exit(0) ?
    }
}, time, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// check
if (input == toGuess) {
    half.cancel();
    full.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, I didn't know about these classes. Though, what I would do in `full` would be positionning a boolean flag to true, meaning the timer has reached the end, so that the main loop can exit. +1 anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) thread that prints out these messages and shuts down the listening program.

Answer (score 0):

It might inspire you :

```
public static class Game extends TimerTask {
    private long    start;
    private long    end;

    public Game(long end) {
        super();
        this.start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < end)
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimerTask task = new Game(10000);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task,0);
}
```

Comment: You while loop is gonna burn your cpu ;-)

Comment: It's just an example, in his case the loop will contain calls to `Scanner` methods, which are blocking methods, so no problem.