# What is the equivalent of javascript setTimeout in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval

I need to implement a function to run after 60 seconds of clicking a button. Please help, I used the Timer class, but I think that that is not the best way.

Comment: This question has some good relevant answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> "I used the Timer class, but I think that that is not the best way."

The other answers assume you are not using Swing for your user interface (button).

If you are using Swing then do **not** use `Thread.sleep()` as it will freeze your Swing application.

Instead you should use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

See the Java tutorial [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: even though this is the accepted answer it is woefully outdated, especially since the advent of java 9. See the answer below about the `delayedExecutor`

Answer (score 64):

Asynchronous implementation with JDK **1.8**:

```
public static void setTimeout(Runnable runnable, int delay){
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            runnable.run();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

To call with lambda expression:

```
setTimeout(() -> System.out.println("test"), 1000);
```

Or with method reference:

```
setTimeout(anInstance::aMethod, 1000);
```

To deal with the current running thread only use a synchronous version:

```
public static void setTimeoutSync(Runnable runnable, int delay) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
        runnable.run();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Use this with caution in main thread – it will suspend  everything after the call until `timeout` expires and `runnable` executes.

Comment: yeah don't do it this way - it will start too many threads, I think the CompletableFuture technique is better

Comment: CompletableFuture still creates a new Thread. See [CompletableFuture.java#2745](https://github.com/netroby/jdk9-dev/blob/a2f7bd42b767c299d0e6cba6f3c5d8f4f32f0874/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.java#L2745).

Comment: huh, is there a way to tell CompletableFuture to use a threadpool instead of creating a new thread each time? or does it already do that?

Comment: Even Java's built-in Timer `class` starts "too many threads": "A facility for threads to schedule tasks for future execution in a background thread." I think this way is actually pretty clean. It doesn't handle the repeat-execution case, but you could always have your task just call settimeout again at the end.

Comment: It's not precisely like javascript setTimeout - setTimeout returns id which can be used for cancelation via clearTimeout

Answer (score 40):

Use Java 9 CompletableFuture, every simple:

```
CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).execute(() -> {
  // Your code here executes after 5 seconds!
});
```

Comment: Snippet not working it shows the error: The method delayedExecutor(int, TimeUnit) is undefined for the type CompletableFuture

Comment: I think I made a mistake, it's for Java 9, not Java 8. Use Java 9 and everything is fine.

Comment: for anyone working with java 9 and up this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 16):

Using the [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

```java
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // here goes your code to delay
    }
}, 300L); // 300 is the delay in millis
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask) you can find some info and examples.

Comment: Thanks, I also needed clearTimeout() alternative so usage is  ... `Timer timer = new Timer(); timer.schedule(...); timer.cancel();`

Comment: It's still useful in 2023. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use `Thread.sleep()` for this purpose. But if you are working in a multithreaded environment with a user interface, you would want to perform this in the separate thread to avoid the sleep to block the user interface.

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(60000);
    // Then do something meaningful...
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do not use `Thread.sleep` as **it will freeze your main thread**, and not simulate setTimeout from JS.

You need to create and start a new background thread to run your code without stoping the execution of the main thread.

One example:

```js
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                this.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            
            // your code here

        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public ScheduledExecutorService = ses;
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    run() {
            //running after specified time
    }
}, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It runs after 60 seconds from `scheduleAtFixedRate`. Check the [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) documentation.

Comment: Can you share how your solution is better than the others? And please also explain what your solution is doing rather than just pasting a piece of code.

Comment: the code creatore was not me. its oracle. better than me , their must explain. pleade refer to this link and read doc.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Thread.sleep()` method.

```
try {

    Thread.sleep(60000);
    callTheFunctionYouWantTo();
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {

}
```

This will wait for 60,000 milliseconds(60 seconds) and then execute the next statements in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is `setTimeout()` method in [underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library.

Code example:

```
import com.github.underscore.Underscore;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Integer[] counter = new Integer[] {0};
        Supplier<Void> incr =
            () -> {
                counter[0]++;
                return null;
            };
        Underscore.setTimeout(incr, 0);
    }
}
```

The function will be started in 100ms with a new thread.

Comment: It is _definitely_ inappropriate to use any sort of "sleep" (on the main or active thread) to do this sort of thing.  (Nor does it call for the use of a thread.)  Some sort of timeout, as suggested here, is definitely called-for.

Also:  in the timeout-handler, be sure that you verify that the condition-of-interest still exists!  (Even if you "delete the timeout" when the condition no longer exists, there is _still_ a miniscule timing-hole left that you cannot completely eliminate.)