# Getting “Connection refused” message while validating all links inside a page using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to validate all the broken links in a page but I'm getting the "Connection refused: connect" message. Below is the code that I have used. I am using chrome driver.

```
public static void verifyLink(String linkUrl) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(linkUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        httpURLConnect.connect();

        if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==200) {
            System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage());
         }

       if(httpURLConnect.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
            System.out.println(linkUrl+" - "+httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - "+ HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
         }

    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase timeout `httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);` from 3 seconds to 5.
Or the second option, maybe you need to set some cooldown, because server start think that you're making DDoS attack.
Try to add timeout. For example [implicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Comment: I executed by increasing the timeout to 10 seconds but did not work. Any other wayout for this issue?

Comment: @ArijitBiswas, as I said, the second option is to make timeout between your calls. I don't know how exactly you need to do this in Java, but this post  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26311872/6066986 may be helpful for you