# Using the function(err, data) in branch.io Journeys Banner

Tags: function, branch.io

Just wanted some help on how I could use the following code to timeout after 5 seconds. Context: This is a Branch.io banner ad and I'm trying to program in such a way that the ad banner closes automatically after 5 seconds. The relevant part of the documentation is given below and I'm new to coding.

‘branch.closeJourney(function(err) { console.log(err); });’

More details here: https://blog.branch.io/7-advanced-controls-to-help-you-optimize-your-journeys/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using, also this question is too broad. Also add more details to exactly what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Hi Spencer, Thanks for your reply. I'm new to coding. But essentially what I'm trying to do here is try and close my Branch.io Journeys banner ad automatically after it's shown for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not a Branch-specific issue as you simply want to call a function (closeJourney) after a certain delay (6 seconds). The Branch method does not have an argument for you to specify a delay because typically, users will press the dismiss button if they do not want to see the banner anymore.

If you want to execute a function after a certain delay, it might be helpful to check out a Java (if you are coding in Android) implementation of the setTimeout method: [What is the equivalent of javascript setTimeout in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311470/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascript-settimeout-in-java)