# I need to time a bubbleSort function, which stops if a certain time limit is reached. How do i do that in java?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
public static long[] bubbleSort(String[] array, long limit) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (array[j].compareTo(array[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    String temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
                }
                if ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > limit * 10) {
                    return new long[] {0L, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime};
                }
            }
        }
        return new long[] {1L, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime};
    }
```

This is the code I wrote. And its not good.
This function takes too much time. But if I remove the if block

```
if ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > limit * 10) {
        return new long[] {0L, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime};
}
```

its a lot faster!
for example: with the if block, time is = `Sorting time:  0 min.  0 sec. 81 ms.`
without the if block =  `Sorting time: 0 min. 0 sec. 15 ms.`
if the limit is = 4ms., then the function will always return without running its full course.

why is this happening? what else can i do?

P.S.: return array's first value is used to check if sort was completed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, to optimize performance what we can try is to move the comparison,

```
if ( System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > limit * 10) {
    return new long[] {0L, System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime};
}
```

to the outer loop, from the nested loop. This provides lots of improvement, if the size of your array, is sufficiently large.

A better way to do it is to use Timer class, or multithreading, as explained in  the following posts:

[Setting Timeout in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311470/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascript-settimeout-in-java)

[How to set a Timer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: thanks! moving the comparison to outer loop solved my problem.