Game lags, what is wrong?
The white square lags when it moves. I do not see anything wrong with the code and since the application is very simple, i don't think the hardware is the issue either.
Video demonstrating the issue: https://youtu.be/B9BweJw2KZk?si=Hr2RrktubZkKU9aa
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    // SCREEN SETTINGS
    final int originalTileSize = 16; //16x16 tile.
    final int scale = 3;
    //the actual tileSize on screen.
    final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale; // 48x48
    //horizontally
    final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    //vertically
    final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol; //768 px.
    final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow; // 576 px;

    //FPS
    int FPS = 60;

    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler();
    Thread gameThread;


    //set player's default position.
    int playerX = 100;
    int playerY = 100;
    int playerSpeed = 4;


    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }


    public void startGameThread() {
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }


    public void run() {
        double drawInterval = 1_000_000_000.0 / FPS; // 0.01666 seconds.
        double delta = 0;
        long currentTime;
        long timer = 0;
        int drawCount = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        while (gameThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                drawCount++;
            }

            if (timer >= 1_000_000_000) {
                System.out.println("FPS: " + drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        if (keyH.upPressed) {
            playerY -= playerSpeed;
        } else if (keyH.downPressed) {
            playerY += playerSpeed;
        } else if (keyH.leftPressed) {
            playerX -= playerSpeed;
        } else if (keyH.rightPressed) {
            playerX += playerSpeed;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(playerX, playerY, tileSize, tileSize);
        g2.dispose();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setResizable(false);
            window.setTitle("2D Adventure");
            GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
            window.add(gamePanel);
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
            gamePanel.startGameThread();
        });
    }
}


import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {


    public boolean upPressed, downPressed, leftPressed, rightPressed;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upPressed = true;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            downPressed = true;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            leftPressed = true;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            rightPressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upPressed = false;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            downPressed = false;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            leftPressed = false;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            rightPressed = false;
        }

    }
}


My activity monitor when the program runs:


I have updated my computer to the latest version.

You are calling method repaint in the gameThread. If I'm not mistaken, that thread is not the EDT. Usually, animation in Swing is achieved via the timer and also, possibly, custom painting.

The
        while (gameThread != null) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            timer += (currentTime - lastTime);
            lastTime = currentTime;
            if (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                drawCount++;
            }

            if (timer >= 1_000_000_000) {
                System.out.println("FPS: " + drawCount);
                drawCount = 0;
                timer = 0;
            }
        }

part is a busy wait and seems to be the culprit of your issues, because it is repeatedly checking for an end-sign to be reached and uses up resources while doing so. Instead you should use the join() method of the thread, which will pause your current thread until the other thread finishes its work. Therefore, try to use gameThread.join() instead.

Where shall i add  gameThread.join() ? I only have two threads though, gameThread and EDT. Both of these threads will never die ?

@SpektraLami if the game thread never dies, then having a join() call for it would make the main thread wait forever. So, if your game never ends and you want to do something while the game is running, then joining the thread is not an option. Instead, either do a polling, executing some stuff "from time to time" with waits in-between (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311470/what-is-the-equivalent-of-javascript-settimeout-in-java) or invoke an event from the child thread when the main thread needs to do something via wait and notify (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)

Game loops that sleeps for a while and hence reduces the CPU usage does not resolve the issue though, which indicates that "busy wait" may not be the reason of the lag...

@SpektraLami then you will need to benchmark your application and detect where the culprit is.

i don't know what the problem is though...
