# How to execute a method every minute

Tags: java

I am new to programming in Java and am making a project where there is a background image and a sun. The sun changes colour based on the time in real life.

My code is as listed below:

```
package demos;
import processing.core.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Trial extends PApplet{
String URL="http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~minnes/palmTrees.jpg";
PImage backgroundImg;



public void setup(){
    size(200,200);
    backgroundImg = loadImage(URL,"jpg");
}

public void draw(){
      int hour = LocalDateTime.now().getHour();       
      int minute = LocalDateTime.now().getMinute();   

      switch(hour){
      case 13:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(238,238,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 14:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(205,205,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 15:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,215,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 16:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(238,201,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 17:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,193,37);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 18:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(205  ,133,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 19:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,0,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5); 
          break;
      }
      case 20:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(211,211,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 21:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(169,169,169);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }

      case 22:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(105,105,105);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 23:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(79,79,79);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 00:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(0,0,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 1:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(79,79,79);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 2:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
      image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
      fill(105,105,105);
      ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
      break;
      }
      case 3:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(169,169,169);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 4:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(211,211,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 5:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
      image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
      fill(255,0,0);
      ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
      break;
      }
      case 6:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(205,133,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5); 
          break;
      }
      case 7:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,193,37);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 8:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(121,29,121);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 9:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(111,209,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;
      }
      case 10:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(230,209,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);  
          break;
      }

      case 11:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,200,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);  
          break;
      }

      case 12:
      {
          backgroundImg.resize(0    ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,209,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);  
          break;
      }



      default:
      {  backgroundImg.resize(0 ,height);
          image( backgroundImg , 0,0);
          fill(255,209,0);
          ellipse(width/4,height/5,width/5,height/5);
          break;

      }
}
           }     
}
```

For now it just executes the draw method once to change the colour of the sun.
I need the draw method to execute every minute to change colour if the hour changes.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

First you need to create a runnable and put your method in it:

```
Runnable drawRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        draw();
    }
};
```

Then schedule an executor:

```
ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(drawRunnable , 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

That way it will be executed every minute.

Just change the time or the `TimeUnit` to change the time between the executions.

Comment: What exactly is the second line of the executor?

Comment: Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens. for the first part of the line 2 meaning until 0.1.

Comment: And for the MINUTES it says insert "Identifier" to complete classbody name

Comment: It works for me in Eclipse Luna. Did you import everything?

Answer (score 2):

Java **Executor API** provides an API for this job.

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool() : Creates a fixed size thread pool 
 that supports delayed and periodic task execution.
```

[Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) 
provides sample code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **ScheduledExecutorService**

Here is an example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for more details please refer same link.

Below code beep every ten seconds for an hour, you can change time as per your requirement

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
  class BeeperControl {
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void beepForAnHour() {
    final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
            public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
        };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
        }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide some informations about what you are doing in your code.

Comment: Yeah, could you please add some comments?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule(new Task(), 60 * 1000);
```

to run after one  time

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SpringMVC 3, you can do as the following

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1000)
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute periodically
}
```

For more info

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html