# Java - Desktop.getDesktop().open() - Wait until file is open?

Tags: java, file, desktop

I'm searching for a solution to wait until a file is opened. My application opens pdf files and displays user-input dialogs but the dialog is overlapped by the pdf file. Is there a way to add a listener or something to show my dialog when the pdf file is fully open?

I could use a delay or pause but that's not exactly what I want.

I'm using

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("my.pdf"));
```

Comment: Did you already find an answer? I need to open a file that may be edited, and wait until it's closed after modification. There is this Desktop functionality, and there is a Runtime class which returns ref to a Process, but it does not open file in default application. I do not know, how to combine them.

Answer (score -1):

You can instead use a [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java), if you know the time the desktop would take to open the PDF file.

```
import java.util.Timer;
...
Timer timer = new Timer();
...
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("my.pdf"));
int openTime = 10*1000; //Let's say it would take 10s to be opened
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Code to show the dialog you need
  }
}, openTime);
```

Comment: "I could use a delay or pause but that's not exactly what I want."

Comment: Using a timer, you do not need to pause or delay the application till the PDF is opened, you can do whatever you need, and the dialog would then open after the timeout.

Answer (score -1):

To open a file I just created, I use this method:

```
// Returns true if the file is unlocked or if it becomes unlocked in the next x seconds
public static boolean isFileUnlockedWithTimeout(File file, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    if (!file.exists())
        // The file does not exist. So it's not locked. (Another approach could be to throw an exception...)
        return true; 
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * timeoutInSeconds;
    while (true) {
        if (file.renameTo(file)) {
            // The file is not locked
            return true;
        }
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > endTime) {
            // After the timeout
            return false;
        }
        // Wait 1/4 sec.
        try { TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

Applied to the initial question:

```
File myFile = new File("my.pdf");
if (isFileUnlockedWithTimeout(myfile, 5)) {
    // File is not locked, we can open it
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
} else {
    System.out.println("File is locked. Cannot open.");
}
```