# How to make JavaFX ScrollPane autoscroll slowly to the bottom?

Tags: java, javafx, scrollpane

I have a `Scrollpane` with large-enough content to active the vertical scroll bar.
`fx:id` of the `Scrollpane` is `myScrollPane`.
I also have a `button` called `Scroll To The Bottom`.
I have set the `Action Event` of the `Scroll To The Bottom` `button` as below in the `fxml` controller.

```
@FXML
private voide myButtonOnAction(ActionEvent evt) {
    myScrollPane.setVvalue(1.0);
}
```

This,however, scrolls to the bottom very fast.It can't be told whether it was scrolled either. I want to know a way to make `Scrollpane` scrolls SLOWLY.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do not use a Timer for this, unless you are prepared to wrap each update to the scrollbar value in a call to [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

The correct approach is to use a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) animation:

```
static void slowScrollToBottom(ScrollPane scrollPane) {
    Animation animation = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2),
            new KeyValue(scrollPane.vvalueProperty(), 1)));
    animation.play();
}
```

Comment: What is "new KeyValue()"

Comment: A key value is the actual change that should take place in an Animation.  As you can see, it changes the scrollPane’s `vvalue` to 1.  Each KeyValue is associated with a particular KeyFrame, which as you can see in the code, will make the KeyValue take effect after 2 seconds.

Comment: amazing it's working! Can you tell me a place to learn javaFX animation Please??

Comment: I would definitely start with the link to the Timeline class documentation that is in my answer;  it explains the concept pretty well.  The documentation of each class in [the javafx.animation package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/package-summary.html) explains its class pretty well, in fact.  You can also try [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/animation.htm).

Answer (score 2):

To be quick I will use a Timer and gradually increment the vValue to 1. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java) thread to see how to use Timer in Java

Comment: Thanks, It is useful to know!

Comment: Caution: this will not use the correct thread, unless your timer makes use of `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: I followed your opinion and here is my code in the below answers section

Comment: I think @VGR's answer is the accurate one. My approach is more like a hack.

Answer (score -1):

```
@FXML
private void myButtonOnAction(ActionEvent evt) {
    double vVal = myScrollPane.getVvalue();
    double d = (1.0-vVal)/100;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        boolean isTheStart = true;
        double difference;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            double currentVVal = myScrollPane.getVvalue();
            if (isTheStart) {
                isTheStart = false;
                difference = (1.0 - currentVVal)/100;
            }
            myScrollPane.setVvalue(currentVVal+difference);
            if (currentVVal >= 1.0) {
                this.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 1*500, 10);
}
```

Comment: This violates the threading rules of JavaFX. You cannot call `myScrollPane.setVvalue(...)` from a background thread.

Comment: @James_D true! What will be the right way to do it in such requirements? I am not really aware of threading rules of JavaFX. Could you please post a reference here to look at?

Comment: The one with the Timeline animation is the best answer :) Mine approach was a hack to start with.

Comment: Best way is to use a timeline. If you use a background thread, the UI must be accessed on the FX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater(...)`.