# How do I execute the Java code after a few minutes? I want a very simple code or function

Tags: java

How do I execute the Java code after a few minutes?

I want very simple code or function. How do I pause a line of code in Java?

Comment: `Thread.sleep`?

Comment: look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Thread.sleep(long mills);`. This function takes a `long` value in milliseconds (thousandths of a second) to pause

Hope this helps!

Comment: package com.journaldev.threads;

public class ThreadSleep {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
               
    }

}

is this right, can u still modify it.

Comment: If you want your code to pause for 5 seconds, simply use `Thread.sleep(5000)` where you want it to pause. That's it.

Comment: For Example : Thread.sleep(1000)
Here, 1000 = 1 second. it will wait for 1 second