# Java while loop with certain time

Tags: java, time, while-loop, timer

I use a consumer to take items from a queue and send the items to an external API

```
public void run(){
    try {
        while(true){
             //will peek() an item from a queue and send it to an external API
             sendRequest(item);
             thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

And have another method to send the request

```
public void sendRequest(JSONibject item){
     // send request

    if(response.getStatus() == 200){
        //will remove the item from the queue
    }
    if(response.getStatus() == 500){
        //keep the item in the queue and set time for resending
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is when I get the 500 response which means the server is not up. I will keep the items in the queue and try to resend the items every 5 mins. How can I control the while loop in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Let `sendRequest` return `true` on success and `false` when it fails.
Then in the while loop, create a 2nd loop:

```
while (!sendRequest(item)) {
    thread.sleep(1000*60*5);
}
```

Or something like this in `sendRequest`:

```
if(response.getStatus() == 500){
    thread.sleep(1000*60*5);
    sendRequest(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Exception here as well.
For example, create custom exception class as

```
public class ServerDownException extends Exception {
      public ServerDownException(String error) {
             super(error);
      }
}
```

...

```
public void run(){
try {
    while(true){
       try {
         //will peek() an item from a queue and send it to an external API
         sendRequest(item);
         thread.sleep(100);
       } catch(ServerDownException ex) {
         thread.sleep(/*milliseconds*/ 5000);
       }
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e){
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
}
```

....

```
public void sendRequest(JSONibject item) throws ServerDownException {
 // send request

if(response.getStatus() == 200){
    //will remove the item from the queue
}
if(response.getStatus() == 500){
    //keep the item in the queue and set time for resending
    throw new ServerDownException("500 Server Down Error");
}
```

}

You can handle different server errors using several custom exception classes.

Comment: A hint: "server up" isn't an [exceptional event](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html) in this case, it's rather the expected case. Renaming the exception to `ServerDownException` would be less confusing as it is thrown in this case.

Comment: Thanks @LuCio. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your whole context but try something like bellow.

So what you need to do is have another `Array` or `ArrayList` or `List` in either the consumer method or globally of type `<JSONibject>`. In this `array/arraylist/list` just add those items that return the `code 500`. Use the `Timer` to schedule to run every 5 minutes and there send all the items from this `array/arraylist/list`.

First, create a timmer by importing it. (Also import TimerTask)

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

Then create a timer object and the ArrayList and Implement the logic somehow like bellow.

```
 public void run() {
    try {
        ArrayList<JSONibject> itemsToResend = new ArrayList<>();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        while (true) {
            //will peek() an item from a queue and send it to an external API
            JSONibject output = sendRequest(item);
            if (output == null) {
                itemsToResend.add(output);
            }

            //This will run evey 5 minutes.
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(itemsToResend.size() > 0){
                        //Apply a loop to send the items again,
                        //Remove those items that are returned null.
                    }
                }
            }, 5 * 60 * 1000, 5 * 60 * 1000);

            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

Kindly look at this thread for more on [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

You would also need to change the `sendRequest` to something like:

```
public JSONibject sendRequest(JSONibject item) {
    // send request

    if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
        //Means consumed
        return null;
    }
    if (response.getStatus() == 500) {
        //Means not consumed and we should retry after 5 min.
        return item;
    }
}
```

Maybe this will give you some starting point or some direction to go.