# Activity onStart() operation results in a blank screen

Tags: android, android-activity, thread-sleep, activity-lifecycle, onstart

I am trying to automatically start a simple timer when the activity shows up. Currently, the activity will not load visibly until my operation is done. Should I override another method?

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer)).setText(String.valueOf(i));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("timer", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question says onStart() method while code is for onResume() method ?

Comment: Have a look at this.
https://thealaskalinuxuser.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/countdown-or-runnable-and-handler-whats-the-difference/
You don't have to call Thread.sleep()

Comment: Thank you @Vivek Mishra - I'v updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are blocking main thread, use Handler with Runnable instead

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: Does this cause the Runnable to possibly modify the TextView off the UI thread, and if so, is that going to be okay?

Comment: well it is not the best option,  I would use MutableLiveData and databinding. In that way you will postValue which is thread safe.

Comment: I understand that the issue is the main thread been blocked. How ever i am still interested for general knowledge to find out if there is another method that is called when the graphics are already been loaded and visible.

Answer (score 1):

Pausing the current thread in order to create a timer is a really bad idea.CheckOut `Timer` class and have a look at `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method in that class and extract `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer))` out from `for` loop.

have a look at 
[How to set a Timer in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044726/how-to-set-a-timer-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

While activity running in onStart(),you may see part of your layout ,not all of your layout.
Maybe you can override method onWindowFocusChanged(),and then start a Thread.
And why you use 'super.onResume()' in onStart()? I don't understand:)

Comment: Yeah, it's a copy paste mistake

Comment: But would onWindowFocusChanged() be called on different events?  for instance screen orientation change?

Comment: All of the Window focus changed ,it will be called,include screen orientation change.The screen orientation change will destory current activity and reCreate it.Sometimes you must save the Activity state.